# Linear regression in R, selecting certain values within a column

Tags: r, lm

If I have a dataset wherein one column is a list, how can I run linear regression including only specific variables in that column?

```
Example.Column <- (DrugA1, Drug A2, DrugA2, DrugA3, DrugB1, DrugB2,
                 DrugB3, No.Drug, Drug A2, No.Drug, DrugB3)
VolMeasure <- c("VL.of.region1", "VL.of.region2", "VL.of.region3")
```

Sorry for the confusion here - there would be a for-loop to have the `lm` go through each `VolMeasure` for the response variable - so there would be 3 regressions in the example.

```
Example.lm <- lm(VolMeasure ~ DrugA1|DrugA2|DrugA3, data=dataset)
```

From this, I need to also figure out how I can do such a thing for multiple variables in one linear regression, so for example if I add a dieting variable

```
Diet.variable<-("Atkins", "Mediterranean", "Caloric Restriction", "None")
Example2.lm<-lm(VolMeasure ~ DrugA1|DrugA2|DrugA3 & Diet.variable=c("Atkins"), data=dataset)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should ?ls and look at the example. It is simple "+" notation.

Comment: What is your actual response here. You can't have multiple responses for a simple linear regression. Your example is very much incomplete and confusing. Please try to make a proper [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm trying to run linear regression on a portion of a dataset - so only looking at the participants that are on one of the A drugs (drug A is a class, and A1/2/3 are subclasses), and how that effects volume measurements. Because of the nature of what I want to do after this, sub-setting is potentially problematic as it separates the data.

Comment: If by chance someone comes across this same sort of problem, here is my solution: Example.lm <- lm(VL.of.region1 ~ Example.Column, data = MyData[MyData$Example.Column %in% c("DrugA1", "DrugA2", "DrugA3"), ])

Comment: The question does not refer to Linear Programming.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make a subset dataset:

```
    subData <- subset(yourData, 
Example.Column %in% c("DrugA1", "DrugA2", "DrugA3") & Diet.Variable == "Atkins")

    lm( VolMeasure ~ Example.Column + Diet.Variable, data = subData)
```